# Log postgresql query positional parameters on error (postgresql 10)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to debug an application that inserts data into a PostgreSQL 10 database.

PostgreSQL complains that a value is too long for type varying(10) and logs something like this:

```
2023-08-22 11:23:03.880 CEST [27693] INSTRUCTION :  UPDATE <table_name> SET "dataUpserted" = now(),"name" = $1,"otherfield" = $2,"notes" = $3,"status" = $4,[...] WHERE "id" = $75
```

What I understand is that PostgreSQL doesn't log query parameters (the $1, $2, ...) but it would really help me understand what part of the input data is faulty. The `log_parameter_max_length_on_error` configuration parameter seems appropriate, but unfortunately it does not exist in PostgreSQL 10. Is there no other way to log query parameters in PostgreSQL 10?